# How to convert DOI to citation information

Tags: resources, citations, research, academic-writing

The [DOI website](http://dx.doi.org/) will redirect to the article webpage on the journal official website. Is there is a public automated system to translate DOI to citation information?

This can be beneficial for preparing references (for examples in LaTex), as each journal has its own web layout and different style for writing citation information of the given article. Thus, it needs extra task to explore each journal website to capture citation information for each article.

Comment: What's a DOI website?

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/ you can resolve each DOI like http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs11023-007-9060-8

Comment: I think this question would be better suited at one of the other SE sites. It seems more technical in nature.

Comment: @StevenDrennon - this seems like it would be suited to web apps, but I do wonder if it also fits here.  Meta would be the place to discuss.  We've already had a general software discussion there.

Comment: **Writers** in a broader sense would eminently suit for this question, so I think we should let it be.

Comment: Thanks folks! Since the audience of this service will be writers, I thought it fits within the scope of SE Writers, and writers are interested in this issue.

Comment: Ali, There's nothing wrong with the question as it is now, but since this question hasn't attracted an answer in the three days it's been here, I suggest adding more information: Why do you need a system like this? What's the benefit of automating it? (And so on.)

Comment: @NeilFein I added more description of usefulness, and I also added more tags to assist people to find the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not certain if it is what you are looking for, but you can get the xml or unixref formatted citations from DOI on the [CrossRef website](http://www.crossref.org/guestquery/).  Also Connotea is freeware that will produce similar citation formats.

If you specifically interested in LaTeX (i.e. BibTeX) formatting, you may be interested in [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/automatically-dereference-doi-to-bib) on the TeX site.

And on the CrossRef site, they have a blog that explains how you can use the same process (as BibTeX formatting) for [different formats](http://www.crossref.org/CrossTech/2011/11/turning_dois_into_formatted_ci.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a copy-paste-click-copy-paste solution, try this:

http://doi-to-bibtex.herokuapp.com

Comment: This site is broken.